# SQL Order By id and Count star not working

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get number of all records and get last record :

```
   $sql_count_sms = "SELECT count(*) as total,content,id FROM android_users_sms WHERE user_id=$id ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result_count_sms = mysql_query($sql_count_sms);
    $row_num_sms = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_count_sms);
    $num_sms     = $row_num_sms['total'];
    $last_my_sms = $row_num_sms['content'];
```

I can get number of records but I can't get last `content` record .
It returns first record !

Where is my wrong ?

---

Below codes works fine, but I think `count(*)` is faster than `mysql_num_rows`  .

```
    $sql_count_sms = "SELECT content,id FROM android_users_sms WHERE user_id=$id ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result_count_sms = mysql_query($sql_count_sms);
    $row_num_sms = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_count_sms);
    $num_sms     = mysql_num_rows($result_count_sms);
    $last_my_sms = $row_num_sms['content'];
```

Any solution?

Comment: you're using aggregate functions without a `group by `, so mysql is free to do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 1):

The grain of the two results you want is not the same.  Without using a sub-query you can't combine an aggregate and a single row into the same result.

Think of the grain as the base unit of the result.  The use of `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions can influence that "grain"... one result row per row on table, or is it grouped by user_id etc...  Think of an aggregate function as a form of grouping.

You could break it out into two separate statements:

`SELECT count(*) as total FROM android_users_sms WHERE user_id = :id;`

`SELECT * FROM android_users_sms WHERE user_id = :id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Also, specific to your question, you probably want a `LIMIT 1` in combination with the `ORDER BY` to get just the last row.

Now, counter intuitively perhaps, this should also work:

```
SELECT count(*), content, id 
FROM android_users_sms 
WHERE user_id = :id 
GROUP BY id, content 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1;`
```

This is because we've changed the "grain" with the `GROUP BY`.  This is the real nuance and I feel like this could probably be explained better than I am doing now.

You could also do this with a sub query like so:

```
SELECT aus.*, 
(SELECT count(*) as total FROM android_users_sms WHERE user_id = :id) AS s1 
FROM android_users_sms AS aus 
WHERE user_id = :id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Marc B's comment brings up the "ambiguity" introduced by what you were doing.